# Interrupts Not Working When I Jump to Application (STM32)

Tags: c++, stm32, stm32f4

Update: Maybe the better question to ask is how should I go about debugging this problem? I'm using VS Code with OpenOCD debugger. I always clean build. The best I can do once I JumpToApplication() is see what addresses the debugger stops at when I pause/step into.

I am able to flash a program into Partition A (@address 0x8060000) and verify it with a CRC check. The program runs anything in while loop fine (LED3 toggling, UART); however, the LED2 toggling based off of a timer interrupt does not work. When I flash the program normally (ie not with my bootloader) it works 100%, including LED2 toggling.

Here are some of the resources I have addressed ([1](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2017/04/tutorial-jump-system-memory-software-stm32/), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/222638/clearing-usart-uart-interrupt-flags-in-an-stm32), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453553/stm32-hard-fault-when-jumping-to-application-from-custom-bootloader), [AN2606](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf)). How do I get the interrupts working for my second application? The resources recommend I clear pending interrupts, but I don't know the best way to approach that.  In my bootloader app I use the ETH, UART and GPIO peripherals so I will go through the manual and read registers to clear the interrupt flags but what about the other interrupts like NMI, HardFault, do I have to figure out how to clear those as well? Through my Google searching I have not found any convenient functions to clear all pending interrupts, does it exist?

Below I include the jump function/linker file for the bootloader application at 0x8000000 and the main.c/linker file for the application at 0x8060000:

JUMP FUNCTION IN BOOTLOADER PROGRAM AT 0x8000000

```
void ApplicationManager::RunActivePartition()
{     
    JumpToApplication = (void (*)(void)) (*((uint32_t *) (active_partition.address + 4)));

    /* Set vector table offset register */
    SetVectorTable(MemoryInfo::BTLR_ADDRESS, MemoryInfo::PARTITION_A_OFFSET_FROM_BTLR);

    /* STM32 needs the stack pointer to start at the beginning of
    ** the application in flash. This must happen last */ 
    __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*) active_partition.address);

    JumpToApplication();


    /*************** Other things I have tried ***************/
    /* Reset RCC clock configuration */
    // HAL_RCC_DeInit();

    /* Disable peripheral clocks */
    // __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
    // __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
    // __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
    // __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_DISABLE();
    // __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_DISABLE();
    // __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();
    // __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_DISABLE();

    /* Disable Peripherals */
    // HAL_CRC_MspDeInit(&hcrc);
    // HAL_UART_DeInit(&huart3);

    /* Disable and reset systick timer */
    // SysTick->CTRL= 0;
    // SysTick->LOAD = 0;
    // SysTick->VAL = 0;

    /* Disable all interrupts */
    // __disable_irq();

    /* Clear pending interrupts */

    /* Remap system memory */
    // SYSCFG->MEMRMP = SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE_0; // 

    /*************** What I want to add when more basic implementation works ***************/
    // /* Relocate vector interrupt table to RAM */
    // CopyVectorInterruptTable();

    // /* TODO: Patch VIT with bootloader interrupt handlers (ex: hard fault handler) */
    // PatchVectorInterruptTable();

    // if (!CopyandPatchOkay())
    // {
    //     LOG_DEBUG("Vector interrupt table not probably copied and/or patched \n");
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //     LOG_DEBUG("Device ready to jump into application \n");
    // }
}
```

LINKER FILE FOR APPLICATION (BOOTLOADER) 0x8000000

```
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20010000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 192K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 2048K
}
```

APPLICATION TO JUMP TO AT 0x8060000

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim10)
{
 HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  SCB->VTOR = 0x8060000; //---- @berendi's suggestion
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM10_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint32_t count = 0;
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim10);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    for (uint32_t i=0; i < 100000; i++);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin);
    _printf("Hi %d \n", count);
    count++;
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

LINKER FILE FOR APPLICATION (INTERRUPT-BLINKY) 0x8060000

```
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20010000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 192K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8060000, LENGTH = 1024K
}
```

Comment: Your "bootloader" code seems to disable all interrupts. Do your main "application" code enable interrupts again?

Comment: I added __enable_irq() as the first line in main in my blinky program. Now both LED's do not toggle.

Comment: FYI: arm KEIL: ARM: How to Write a Bootloader:  http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3913.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In projects generated by STM32CubeMX, the `SystemInit()` function in `system_stm32f4xx.c`, called by the startup code before `main()`, resets the vector table address register to the start of the FLASH.

```
/* #define VECT_TAB_SRAM */
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET  0x00 /*!< Vector Table base offset field.
                                   This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */

/* -- snip -- */

#ifdef VECT_TAB_SRAM
  SCB->VTOR = SRAM_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal SRAM */
#else
  SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */
#endif
```

You can edit this file directly (and not run STM32CubeMX on the project again, because it [appears to overwrite this file](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426275/how-to-handle-configuration-changes-to-the-project-with-stm32cubemx)), or simply set the right value again in `main()`, before enabling interrupts.

Comment: I added SCB->VTOR = 0x8060000; to my application and it works! Thanks @berendi. Any idea why the debugger didn't update the VTOR register in my viewer after I jumped? I was watching for this.

Comment: Thank you for this. 'SCB->VTOR = ((uint32_t)FIRMWARE_START_ADDR);' also worked for me.